# Vertices causing UV map to flip in one area

Tags: modeling, uv, vertices

I'm using a dieline to recreate a some packaging and have run into an issue. The cutout on the right hand side appears to be messing up my UV Map. The cut-out vertices seem to attached to vertices at the bottom of the face.[image: Screenshot] 
Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Im not sure exactly where the problem is, but to avoid errors, you need to triangulate n-gon faces before unwrapping.

Comment: I think you should put an image of the problem showing the Uv/Image editor window where you show the uv map in question